# When need InvalidateSurface()?

Tags: xamarin

In the example below, 
OnTouchEffectAction contains canvas.InvalidateSurface().
OnCanvasViewPaintSurface contains convas.DrawPath().

Questions:

1. Why OnTouchEffectAction requires InvalidateSurface()?
2. Why doesnt call InvalidateSurface after
       drawing?

[image: Screenshot is given here]

[Complete Code is given here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/effects-touchtrackingeffect/)

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images.  Take the time to paste your code as text and format it so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

`InvalidateSurface` causes the `PainSurface` event to be raised, which calls `OnCanvasViewPaintSurface`.  `InvalidateSurface` is how you tell Skia that you've made changes to a canvas and that it's UI needs to be refreshed.  `OnTouchEffectAction` is adding new polylines to the canvas, so calling `InvalidateSurface` causes the canvas to be redrawn with those new lines.